# SOQL join in a Parent Child for same table (Account)

Tags: soql, inner-join, outer-join

I want to write this simple soql query where in Account there is a ParentId and with it would want to bring the name of this parent (Hierarchy field)
Something like:

```
select Id, Name, (select Name from Account__r where Id = Account.ParentId)
From Account where id = [xxxxxxx]
```

I know my Where statement is wrong, just wanted to clarify what it is I want
I have seen many examples of join but never where it is the same table.

Comment: I think you are looking for self join, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need any additional filters to make sure the children are related to the parent. If you write the below query, each row will have an attribute named `ChildAccounts` which contains each `Account` record whose `ParentId` matches the row's own `Id` value.

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Name FROM ChildAccounts) FROM Account
```

If you want to select the parent record instead of children, you would instead do:

```
SELECT Parent.Name FROM Account
```

Comment: I think the result might be inverted from what I want.
If I were to write it in standard SQL it would be:

`SELECT a.Id, a.Name, b.Name  FROM Account a
left Join Account b  on a.ParentId = b.Id
WHERE a.id = xxxxxx`